# Mobaxterm profile will be reset when I restart the Mobaxterm

Tags: terminal, putty, mintty

I use home edition `Mobaxterm`,and my `/etc/baseprofile` will be reset when I restart the `Mobaxterm`. Not only `/etc/baseprofile`, but also other files, such as `/etc/hosts` will meet the same situation.

How can figure out this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the limitation of the home edition as precised in the banner that is displayed on each of the window you open and in http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html :

> Customize your startup message and logo 
>   Modify your profile script

If you make the root of your MobaXTerm local to your disk you can modify the /home/mobaxterm/.bashrc to do your customization. You can always use the portable version (no Administrator rights are needed) but you will have a subdirectory MxtRoot somewhere on your local disk.